# Scraping large images from a websites zoom feature

Tags: html, image, perl, web-scraping, image-scaling

I need to scrape images and/or the urls of the images from a website for a client. I have a list of URLs that take you to a specific product page containing product images, product description...and so on (as shown below).

**My example URL list** (using Firebox's website purely because it has a good example of my problem):

http://www.firebox.com/product/6078/Back-To-The-Future-iPad-Case?via=hp&s=1x1&t=livefeed
http://www.firebox.com/product/5773/Scientific-Spice-Rack?via=hp&s=1x1&t=random
http://www.firebox.com/product/6147/Rice-Cube?via=related

**The problem I am having:**

If you go to one of these URLs you can see that the website shows a number of product images.

**If you then click one of the images it then displays a larger version of the image.** It is this larger dimension images that I require (typically around 980 x 980) that are displayed when you click to zoom the image rather than the smaller images (typically around 250 x 250) that are initially displayed when you go to the product page.

[image]

**The reason the client needs the larger dimension images** is because he displays large images on his website that are automatically scaled to 1200 x 1200 and when smaller images are used if they are not already this size it makes the image look blurry/pixelated.

How would I go about getting these larger dimension images from the site rather than the smaller ones?

I have looked at possible ways to do this using Perl (as this is what I know) such as Selenium, but cannot see a way it is possible to actually get the larger dimension images. This is a new topic to me.

Comment: You should keep in mind that it is not legal to just take someone else's images and display them on your client's website. In Europe, there are entire law firms living off people who make that mistake.

Comment: @simbabque - In this particular case we have explicit written permission to do so...but it is certainly a very valid comment as this is definitely not always the case. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is just about extracting the link to the large image from HTML source of the page.
If you view the HTML source of http://www.firebox.com/product/5773/Scientific-Spice-Rack?via=hp&s=1x1&t=random you can actually see the links to big images, see part of HTML below:

```
<img class="extra_thumb" data-item="0"   data-sku="sku14014"  data-zoom-image="http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_column_grid_12.jpg" data-caption="" data-image="http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_column_grid_6.jpg"  src="http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_column_grid_1.jpg"/>
```

You can see the link to the large image in `data-zoom-image` or `data-image` so it's all about extracting it with regex. You can use Perl, Python or many other languages for this.
Here is a short Perl example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw( uniq );

my $content = get('http://www.firebox.com/product/5773/Scientific-Spice-Rack?via=hp&s=1x1&t=random');
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;

my (@big_images) = $content =~ /data-zoom-image\=\"([^\"]+?)\"/g;
say for uniq @big_images;
```

Above prints:

```
http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_column_grid_12.jpg
http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_extra1_column_grid_12.jpg
http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_extra2_column_grid_12.jpg
http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_s14019_column_grid_12.jpg
http://media.firebox.com/pic/p5773_s14014_column_grid_12.jpg
```

Comment: I would not necessarily parse it with regex, but the best approach imho.

Comment: What would you use instead of regex @simbabque?

Comment: @simbabque - How would you parse it instead? Thanks

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the website. If there is only one image, this approach is ok I guess. If the website has many images per page, a parser like Web::Scraper might be a good idea. However, this gets the job done. :)

Comment: @user3195726 - Whats the reason it duplicates the urls in your output? thanks a lot

Comment: The URLs that are duplicated N times simply appear N times in HTML source (Regex matches all appearances on @big_images). If you would like to get unique ones only you could use List::MoreUtils module. In the beginning of the code put "use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq)" and then "say for uniq @big_images;". I editem my answer.

Comment: @user3195726 - I have a similar but more complicated example that I am struggling with. A good example of the problem I am facing is shown on this site `http://www.iwantoneofthose.com/gift-travel/on-the-run-notebooks/30000128.html`. If you use Firebug to look at the html the large images required are just identified using `href=`. This would mean if I used your example above I would get all the href links on the whole page which is obviously not wanted. How would I go about doing this for examples like the one I described above? thanks for all your help

Comment: There's nothing more complicated about it really. Just change your regex to have a wider match: `my (@big_images) = $content =~ /<li[^>]+?class=\"list-item\">\s*<a[^>]+?href=\"([^\"]+?)\"[^>]*?>/g;`. Also read about regexes: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html as you don't seem to understand what the code above actually does...